# Extern variable not behaving as expected

Tags: c, embedded, extern

*scom.h*

```
extern byte i;
```

*scom.c*

```
byte i;
void interrupt_Rx(void)
{
    byte data;
    data = SCI0DRL; // data taken from SCI0
    i = SCI0DRL;
    // code ( in this code, variable i is not used)
}
```

*app.c*

```
#include "Scom.h"

extern byte i;
byte j; // global variable
```

In one of the function defined in app.c, I am assigning `i` to `j`;

```
void fun(void)
{
    //some code
    j=i;
    //operations on j;
    j = j & 0x0F;
    k = j +0x30;
    lcd_puta(k);// displaying k on LCD
}
```

Expected value for `j` is `j = 0x07` and for `k = 0x37`

after using breakpoint at `j=i;` value of `j` itself is random value.
Why so? did I make any mistake??

Comment: `but i am not able to operate on i/j.`  kindly elaborate

Comment: What result are you getting? And what result did you expect? And how do you check the values?

Comment: @SouravGhosh : operations like j=j&0x0F; k=j+0x30 and then displaying k on LCD

Comment: Please add this information to the question and not as a comment. Otherwise most people will not read it. You can click on the [edit] link to edit your question.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg some random values .. fatleast i am expecting j as 0x77 after execution of j=i; statement

Comment: a breakpoints stops it *before* executing the line

Comment: 1. Is your final result correct on LCD? 2. Have you enabled debugging while compiling your code?

Comment: @Spalteer no after execution, it stops and can debug stepwise...

Comment: @MohitJain No. I am not getting correct LCD result

Comment: presumably the declaration in scom.c is outside of any function?

Comment: Is there other codes that may affect the global variables `i` and `j`? If is, I suggest making a small test project which only contains the codes above(of course some extra codes to make it compilable and runnable) to see whether it's correct.

Comment: I suspect the 'some code' before the assignment 'j=i' ... what is that 'some code' doing ? Could it be corrupting the value of 'i' or 'j'  ... ? A bitwise '&' of 0x77 and 0x0F should give 0x07 as you expect ...

Comment: First of all `app.c` has to `#include "scom.h"` and not redefine `extern byte i;`. i is a very common used variable: are you sure that scom.c is compiled and the i is not referring to another i not initialized i? Could you post the `//some code` before `j=i`?

Comment: @LPs: The is not a definition, but a declaration. Allthough uncommon, it is very well correct and the same (for the compiler) like including a header containing it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keeping *scom.h* as is, your *app.c* should have `#include "scom.h"`
2. Confirm that variable `i` of the type `byte` is declared as `volatile byte i;` and not being updated in any other piece of code after the ISR is executed and before it is assigned to `j` in `func()`.
3. In your function

   ```
   void fun(void)
   {
      //some code
      j=i;
      //operations on j;
      j = j & 0x0F;
      k = j + 0x30;
      lcd_puta(k);// displaying k on LCD
   }
   ```

   `i` is not declared locally in `//some code`, else `i` will be taken locally due to block scope. You said that,

   > > after using breakpoint at j=i; value of j itself is random value.

Reading this doesn't make clear if you have a breakpoint *after* the instruction *i.e.* at the next instruction or to the line where it says `i=j;` If latter the case then, 'j' is yet to be assigned with the value of 'i'. Instead have `i` in watch window while debugging.

This doesn't look like happening in your case but, I can see that `j` is a global variable, is it `extern`ed elsewhere and modified by some other ISR than the one shown in the post?
Being blind to that part of code (if it is there) I can predict that there are chances that one such ISR(if it is there) that change value of `j` after is it assigned with `i` and before being printed. For example:

```
    ISR(TIMER_0)
    {
       //Clear and disable interrupt
       j += 1; //can be anything that modifies j.
       //Enable interrupt
    }

    void fun(void)
    {
       //some code
       j=i;
       //operations on j;    
       j = j & 0x0F;         // Interrupt received here Or
       k = j + 0x30;         // Interrupt received here
       //Here value of `k` is different than what is expected, obviously
       lcd_puta(k);// displaying k on LCD
    }
```

I am assuming that `k` is of the compatible data type, preferably of the type `byte`.

Though its not a really strict rule, should you declare a variable in an ISR? No, you shouldn't. Assuming the subroutines use the same register bank of course, Interrupts may have local variables just like normal functions. But, higher levels of optimization in the compiler will move variables automatically into the registers, thus saving them when an interrupt triggers. Please do not declare `byte data;` in `void interrupt_Rx(void)`.

Comment: @Olaf: While I agree about returning `void`, I do have a thought on declaring variables in an ISR. For optimization purpose, the compiler move the variables into the registers.

Comment: 1) you don't _return_ void; this is plain **nothing**; actually "void" is no type, but - well - exactly what it says. You really should read the standard about this. And what would be the point about locals and the compiler? Share your thougths please; what would be the problem with the compiler using registers for locals (no idea what you mean by "move into ..."). On most RISC CPUs (ARM e.g.) you have to use registers anyway, as they do not support memory operands.